# запуск selenium в crontab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, crontab

Код запуска моего скрипта кроном

```
DISPLAY=:0
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 '/home/some-path/main.py'
```

Код main.py

```
 from selenium import webdriver
    
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(
           executable_path=r'/home/some-path/Рабочий стол/geckodriver',
           firefox_binary=r'/home/some-path/firefox/firefox')
 driver.get('https://www.google.ru/')
```

Почему браузер открывается с пустой вкладкой, хотя я явно указал страницу, которую хочу открыть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением стало использование Chrome вместо Firefox:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/some-path/chromedriver')
```